# Adobe Air application has black bars on iPhone 5 on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, air, ios7

On iPhone 5s using iOS7 (not tested 6) my application has black bars on the left and right sides of the screen reducing the screen size, but is correctly opening fullscreen on every other iOS device I have so far tested. Screenshot below.

[image]

I have been searching and have not found any mention of this as a bug, have replicated on two iPhone 5's iOS7 devices though and is definitely a problem.

I'm using Air 3.9.

Has anyone encountered this / know how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to include an extra iOS splash screen

**Default-568h@2x.png**

There is a full list of images here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html, apparently a few Air apps have been getting rejected because they are missing the new iOS7 size images.

Example images:

**Default.png** - 320 x 480 -  iPhone, standard resolution

**Default@2x.png** - 640 x 960 - iPhone, high resolution

**Default-568h@2x.png** - 640 x 1136 - iPhone, high resolution, 16:9 aspect ratio

**Default-Portrait.png** - 768 x 1004 (AIR 3.3 and earlier) 768 x 1024 (AIR 3.4 and higher) - iPad, portrait orientation

**Default-Portrait@2x.png** - 1536 x 2008 (AIR 3.3 and earlier) - 1536 x 2048 (AIR 3.4 and higher) - iPad, high resolution, portrait orientation

**Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png** - 768 x 1004 (AIR 3.3 and earlier)768 x 1024 (AIR 3.4 and higher) - iPad, upside down portrait orientation

**Default-PortraitUpsideDown@2x.png** - 1536 x 2008 (AIR 3.3 and earlier)1536 x 2048 (AIR 3.4 and higher) - iPad, high resolution, upside down portrait orientation

**Default-Landscape.png** - 1024 x 768 - iPad, left landscape orientation

**Default-LandscapeLeft@2x.png** - 2048 x 1536 - iPad, high resolution, left landscape orientation

**Default-LandscapeRight.png** - 1024 x 768 - iPad, right landscape orientation

**Default-LandscapeRight@2x.png** - 2048 x 1536 - iPad, high resolution, right landscape orientation

**Default-example.png** - 320 x 480 - example:// URL on standard iPhone

**Default-example@2x.png** - 640 x 960 - example:// URL on high-resolution iPhone

**Default-example~ipad.png** - 768 x 1004 - example:// URL on iPad in portrait orientations

**Default-example-Landscape.png** - 1024 x 768 - example:// URL on iPad in landscape orientations

Comment: That's not an icon that you missed, that's a splash screen (Default-568h@2x.png)

Comment: Could someone provide an example of how this would look? Like would I need to just "include" this with the IDE import and not "use them" in the code or do I have do use if/else logic? Thanks so much!

Comment: @PapaDeBeau I use Air and it is a case of just putting them in the correct folder. I would imagine it's the same in xcode, I'd guess you will be able to find a starter template with dummy images included.

Comment: I use Air too. so what folder do I put them in and  do I need to call them in the  As3 or just do an include in the Flash IDE? :)

Comment: I use FlashDevelop to publish, the starter template has a folder called icons where both the iOS and Android splash screens go

Comment: In the application.xml these images are referenced

Comment: For the Flash IDE? Man I can't find them.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau It looks like it is generated automatically.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-48bca492124b39ac5e2-7ffb.html

Comment: Yes, I added it with the application by using the PLUS sign and adding the file to the root. That seemed to work.